# Using Result Source with CoreResultsWebPart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, migration, search-scope, result-source

I am in the process of migrating a SP2010 solution to 2013.

Previously we had a CoreResultsWebPart configured to use a Search Scope, but as this functionality has been removed in 2013, the advice given is to use Result Sources instead.

I have set up a Result Source that behaves in a similar manner to the Search Scope, but how to I tell my web part to actually use the Result Scope?

EDIT:

This is the options I see when I edit the webpart

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit the web part and change the Query to use your Result Source.
[image]

Comment: I don't see that option for the CoreResultsWebPart

Comment: You are working in 2013 right?

Comment: I don't see a screen that looks like that

Comment: edited my question with what I see

Comment: It looks like you are using the 2010 web parts on your 2013 search site. You should create a new search center rather than use the 2010 web parts. You want to be using the ResultScriptWebPart.